# Cannot get text value from dropdown control jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a table that users can add rows to using append. Options are being updated dynamically.I have a dropdown within the row but cannot find a way to get to the text. I can retrieve value only. I've tried replacing .val() for .text() but it doesnt work.

```
<td>Role<br/><select id="ddlDepartment" class="ddlDepartment" name="D1"><option value="">
        Select Role</option></select></td>

<!-- language : lang-js -->
 $("table.tbl_id_1").on("change", 'input[name^="txt"]', function (event) {
        calculateRow($(this).closest("tr"));

    });


    function calculateRow(row) {
    var price = +row.find('input[name="txtVision"]').val();
    price += +row.find('input[name="txtInitiate"]').val();  

    var txtddl = +row.find('select.ddlDepartment').val();
    }
```

Comment: can you explain you question a bit! what do you actually want to achieve?

Comment: You need to use parseInt in the context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you are trying to get the text of the selected value from the `select` element.

try

```
var txtddl = +row.find('select.ddlDepartment:selected').val();
```

the above code will give you the selected value of the `select` object.
if you want the text inside the selected item just use

```
var txtddl = +row.find('select.ddlDepartment:selected').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$("#ddlDepartment").children("option").is("selected").text()
```

Comment: Object doesn't support property or method 'text' 
var txtddl = $(".ddlDepartment").children("option").is("selected").text();
Any ideas?